# Find maximum and minimum of $f(x, y) = xy$ on $D = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+2y^2 \leq 1 \right\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm kinda stuck on this one :

> Find the minimum and maximum of the given function $f$ on $D$, where $$f(x, y) = xy$$ and $$D = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+2y^2 \leq 1 \right\}$$

I don't know what to do with this domain $D$. I counted the first derivatives and got only point $(0,0)$ as a possible maximum/minimum inside $D$ but what about the boundary of $D$? Should I parametrize this ellipse or how should I approach this? Thanks for your tips!

Comment: I'm sorry, but What exactly "minimum of maximum" means?

Comment: sorry, was meant to be "minimum and maximum" just like in the title :)

Comment: Without calculus $x=\cos\theta, y=\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt2}\implies xy=\cos\theta\cdot \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sin2\theta}{2\sqrt2}$ and $-1\le \sin2\theta\le1$

Comment: Would you know how to solve the same problem if $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$?

Comment: Yes, parametrize the circle as $x = \cos t$, $y = \sin t$ and look at $z(t) = \cos t + \sin t$ where $t \in [0, 2\pi]$, find solutions of $z'(t)$.

Comment: @darenn but that would give only solutions in the border of the area. I agree that the maximum is there due to the $f(x,y)=xy$, but would not that have to be demonstrated too?

Comment: Yes, but the inner circle is checked by checking the first derivatives, I did that as mentioned in the main post :)

Comment: And $xy$ is continuous for any order... ok, missed that bit.

Comment: You can check this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420253/maximum-and-minimum-of-fx-y-xy-in-the-region-between-y-0-and-y-x2-4/420292#420292 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415154/lagrange-multiplier-constrain-critical-point/415285#415285 for the general strategy (in one case the function is even the same!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the function $f$ has no relative extreme inside the desired region $D$. In favt using the routine method we will find $(0,0)$ a saddle point in which $f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy}^2)<0$. Now consider $D$ and that $$x=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$$ Putting each parts $x=+$ and then $x=-$ separately we will find two one-variable functions $$f(y)=+y\sqrt{1-y^2}, ~~~f(y)=-y\sqrt{1-y^2}$$ I think you can find the relative extremes of these functions.... You have $4$ points as I plotted below:

[image]

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks ^__^

Answer (score 1):

As you said above the critical points at the rim can be found by parameterization. To parameterize the ellipse, use the following: $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=2\sin(t)$ As for the rest of the interval, first take the gradient of the function:

$$\nabla{f(x,y)}=\langle{y,x}\rangle$$

It equals $\vec{0}$ when $x=0$ and $y=0$, making $(0,0)$ the only critical point in the function (it also lies within the interval). Compare it to the critical point(s) you found on the boundary to find the minimum and maximum.

Comment: Well yea I know how to find the crit points in the inner circle, I'm just curious how to do the ellipse parametrization :)

Comment: To parameterize an ellipse, say $x = a\cos(t)$ and $y = b\sin(t)$ where $a$ is the length of the horizontal axis and $b$ is the length of the vertical axis.  For a rotated ellipse?  Use a rotation matrix.

Comment: @darenn See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved rather easily by elementary methods without using calculus.

By AM-GM inequality, $$x^2+2y^2\geq 2(x^2\cdot 2y^2)^{1/2}=2\sqrt{2} xy$$ Hence we have $2\sqrt{2} xy\leq 1$, that is $xy\leq1/2\sqrt{2}$. Also note that the equality is achieved at $x=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $y=1/2$.

For the other inequality note that $$1\geq x^2+2y^2=(x+\sqrt{2}y)^2-2\sqrt{2}xy\geq -2\sqrt{2} xy$$ Hence we have $xy\geq -1/2\sqrt{2}$ and the equality is a achieved at $x=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $y=-1/2.$